# Python regex capture multiple matches spanning over multiple lines

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract blocks of data being output by adb which spans over multiple lines using python `re`.

The example data is:

```
* ReceiverList{ac5847f 494 system/1000/u-1 local:ecc819e}
app=494:system/1000 pid=494 uid=1000 user=-1
Filter #0: BroadcastFilter{db24c4c}
Action: "android.app.action.DEVICE_POLICY_MANAGER_STATE_CHANGED"
Action: "android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT"
Action: "android.intent.action.USER_ADDED"
Action: "android.intent.action.USER_REMOVED"
AutoVerify=false
* ReceiverList{d0a75c1 494 system/1000/u-1 local:22946a8}
app=494:system/1000 pid=494 uid=1000 user=-1
Filter #0: BroadcastFilter{19b2166}
Action: "android.intent.action.USER_ADDED"
Action: "android.intent.action.USER_REMOVED"
AutoVerify=false
Filter #1: BroadcastFilter{e1e7ca7}
Action: "android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"
Action: "android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"
Scheme: "package"
AutoVerify=false
* ReceiverList{4b668d3 691 com.android.systemui/10016/u0 remote:523b2c2}
app=691:com.android.systemui/u0a16 pid=691 uid=10016 user=0
Filter #0: BroadcastFilter{bcd1c10}
Action: "android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION"
Action: "android.media.STREAM_DEVICES_CHANGED_ACTION"
Action: "android.media.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED"
Action: "android.media.INTERNAL_RINGER_MODE_CHANGED_ACTION"
Action: "android.media.STREAM_MUTE_CHANGED_ACTION"
Action: "android.os.action.ACTION_EFFECTS_SUPPRESSOR_CHANGED"
Action: "android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGED"
Action: "android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF"
Action: "android.intent.action.CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS"
AutoVerify=false
...
```

What I am trying to extract each set of data that starts with `* ReceiverList...` and ends with the last `AutoVerify=false`. Some of the datasets have multuple `AutoVerify=false`. The final output should reflect `[*ReceiverList...AutoVerify... , *ReceiverList...Autoverify...]`

A few of the things I have tried so far are:

- `re.findall(r'^\*.Receiver.+', data, flags=re.M)` which gives the desired affect but only one the first line.
- `re.findall(r'^\*.Receiver.+AutoVerify=\w+$', data, flags=re.M|re.DOTALL)`, this captures both sets of data.
- `re.findall(r'^\*.Receiver.+(?=AutoVerify=\w+)', data, flags=re.M)`, this does not suffice either.

Please note that in the example dataset, there are two `AutoVerify=false`. In the second set, I would like to include all the data till the next `* ReceiverList` starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `split` to split on newlines with lookahead for `\* ReceiverList`:

```
re.compile("\r?\n(?=\* ReceiverList)").split(s)
```

Comment: Great! I see my error in the `$` in my second test case.

Comment: Ah i spoke to soon @CertainPerformance. In your solution, the pattern matches the first match of `Autoverify` but not the second one.

Comment: Check again - it works just fine for me? https://repl.it/repls/ElementaryLoyalMethod

Comment: If you see the output, you will see it has 2 `AutoVerifiy`. It is failing to capture the autoverify under Filter #1 in the dataset. https://regex101.com/r/yfcjjG/2

Comment: There are only 2 `ReceiverList`s, not 3, so only 2 substrings are matched. There is no `ReceiverList` for the third with `Filter #1`, so it wasn't matched - you said you wanted to extract each set of data that starts with `* ReceiverList`.

Comment: Yes right, but Filter #1 falls under the secent `* ReceiverList`. And that data repeats. I will add a bit more data to the example dataset for clarification

Comment: Ok, see edit - probably easier to just use `split` instead

Comment: Thanks! This is so close, but as you see, in the case of the problematic second dataset, it creates two entries in the list. Index 2 really is a part of index one. So it is not fully curving out the data as a while. And because the Filter # can be arbitrary, as the data scales, the solution doesnt.

Comment: Oops, my mistake, lookahead for `ReceiverList` instead

Answer (score 1):

You can try this pattern: `\* ReceiverList((?!\* ReceiverList)[\w\W])+AutoVerify=false`

It will match boundaries literally: `\* ReceiverList` and `AutoVerify=false`.

Everything between those two, will be matched with this pattern `((?!\* ReceiverList)[\w\W])+`, which says: match one or more occurences of any character (`[\w\W]`) that is not preceeded by `\* ReceiverList`, so wo don't jump over to other message.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rQ15wP/1)

Even simplier: `\* ReceiverList((?!\* ReceiverList)[\w\W])+`.